# Handling mutliple client connections as a server

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a simple form of client-server application, using python. So I got started with sockets, and facing some errors I searched a bit and saw that no two sockets can be listening to the same port at the same time. Is that true? And if so, the only way to handle multiple requests towards the server, as regards the sockets, is to have a single socket do the listening and take turns at the incoming requests?

Comment: When you call `accept()`, it returns a new socket for the connection, the original socket is still listening for new connections.

Comment: That clarifies things quite much. Thank you.

Comment: Also check this please: [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `accept()`, it returns a new socket for the connection, the original socket is still listening for new connections.
                    – Barmar